# save \ share matlab code with function dependencies

Tags: matlab, dependencies, save

I wrote a Matlab script that calls some functions that are exist in my path (that I wrote as well).
I'd like to share this code, but often I need to look for all these function dependencies and copy these functions one by one.
Is there an easy and automatic way to share my code such as all the functional dependencies are addressed?

For example

```
a = 1;
b = fun1(a^2); % fun1 is in some other folder in the matlab path 
c = fun2(b);    % fun2 is in some other folder in the matlab path
save_fully('my_code.zip') % the function I'd like to have that 
                          % generates a zip file with all the m files needed to run the example
```

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/packaging-guis-as-apps.html

Comment: will that work when my code is not a gui or app ?

Comment: That page lists the functionality you can use to list a function’s dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume your example is called by a script called `myScript.m`. You can use [`matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/identify-dependencies.html) to get the required files and products for it to run:

```
[fList, pList] = matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts('myScript.m');
```

It is then just a matter of copying the files listed in `fList` to a folder (e.g., using [`copyfile`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/copyfile.html)) and zipping it using [`zip`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zip.html).